# JDBC ResultSet casting cost

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a noticeable difference, in terms of performance, when reading from ResultSet in these three cases:

1.

```
String name = resultSet.getString(1);
user.name = name;
```

2.

```
Object name = resultSet.getObject(1);
user.name = (String)name;
```

3.

```
String name = resutlSet.getObject(1, String.class);
user.name = name;
```

Are these methods similar and make the same casts? Or when type provided JDBC internally optimizes conversion? Which is the most performant of three?

Comment: why not go for `user.name=resultSet.getString(1);`?

Comment: It's more a readability issue then a performance issue

Comment: #3 does not compile. Only #2 is a cast. There is no good reason to use *any* of these in preference to `user.name = resultSet.getString(1)`.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer

Comment: well, it answered it. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultSet` is interface, you have to take a look on the exact implementation provided by your jdbc driver.

But I guess majority of implementations use pretty the same logic.

1. `resultSet.getObject(1)` - the worst case. In order to identify the result type the driver must check all possible types.
2. `resutlSet.getObject(1, String.class)` in this case the driver will switch by class and identify the right type. This will perform better than the previous one but still not optimal.
3. `resultSet.getString(1)` - the optimal one. The driver already knows the type, it will not perform any sort of filtering.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for [`ResultSet#getObject()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSet.java.html) looks something like this:

```
public Object getObject(int columnIndex) throws java.sql.SQLException {
    // ...
    switch (field.getSQLType()) {
        case Types.CHAR:
        case Types.VARCHAR:
        case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
            return getString(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

In other words, calling `getObject()` on a column which is a text type will just call `getString()` under the hood.  In other words, on the JDBC side of things I would expect all three of your scenarios to perform fairly similarly.  With regard to an extra cast from `Object` to `String` in your Java code, I view this a relatively minor difference.  Of course, if you can avoid a cast you might want to do that.